# Pivot Data in Crystal Reports v. 8

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Reports version 8 in conjunction with SQL Server 2008.  I have a query that produces something like this:

```
NAME       ADDRESS       C/S/Z      EMPLOYER      ETC
JOHN DOE   123 ANY ST    TOWN, USA  JOB INC.      ...
```

I am trying to make it look like this on the Crystal Report:

```
NAME     JOHN DOE
ADDRESS  123 ANY ST
C/S/Z    TOWN, USA
EMPLOYER JOB INC.
ETC      ...
```

I am not certain how to do this with PIVOT in the query because I believe that aggregates and the data we are using is text and does not need aggregation.

Is there a way to just turn the query data on its side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your best bet (IMHO) would be do it in SQL itself and return data to report. Although you might get some way to do it in CR, my personal experience is you wont achieve exactly what you want. In CR there is something called as Cross tab to get you started

Comment: Will give that a shot!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to manipulate the query then one way out would be create saperate formulas for all the fields and then place one below one in detail section.